# Search a Range of Cells to find the only cell that is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have lists of data that run horizontally and output a number based on a forumla. The end result is that 1 cell will have a number, and the other 5 cells will be completely blank. I am trying to find a way to use a formula or function to return the one value in the range of data. [image]

So far I have tried a few things:

-I tried using a sum formula and also a forumla adding each cell seperately. Neither worked and returned either nothing at all or 0.

-I tried using a mix of if and isblank to identify when a cell was blank, and then perhaps go to the next cell until it found a cell with a value and returned that value, but this did not work, it returned a blank cell. The exact formula I used was: =IF(OR(ISERROR(F11),ISBLANK(F11)),1,IF(OR(ISERROR(G11),ISBLANK(G11)),0.75,IF(OR(ISERROR(H11),ISBLANK(H11)),0.5,IF(OR(ISERROR(I11),ISBLANK(I11)),0.4,IF(OR(ISERROR(J11),ISBLANK(J11)),0.25,K11)))))

-The last thing I tried was hlookup. I used =HLOOKUP("*", F12:K12,1,0), but then realized that the "*" only applied to text, so I tried "<>", "< >" and "&", but those did not work.

If anyone has a way to achieve this, I would definitely appreciate it. I feel like this should be a pretty simple function, so I must be doing something wrong or missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: `=INDEX(G2:K2,MATCH(1E+99,G2:K2))`

Comment: Hello @ScottCraner, that is giving me an #N/A error unfortunately

Comment: Then your numbers are stored as text and not numbers.  Can you show the formula that inputs the numbers?

Comment: Yes, each is slightly different but achieves a similar result

F column: =IF(AND(B2>=MIN($M$1)), "1","")
G: =IF(AND(B2>=MIN($M$2,$N$2),B2<=MAX($M$2,$N$2)), ".75","")
H: =IF(AND(B2>=MIN($M$2,$N$2),B2<=MAX($M$2,$N$2)), ".5","")
I: =IF(AND(B2>=MIN($M$2,$N$2),B2<=MAX($M$2,$N$2)), ".4","")
...etc

Comment: Remove the `"` around the numbers.  it is inserting them as text and not a number.